# Speed of SELECT Distinct vs array unique

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using WordPress with some custom post types (just to give a description of my DB structure - its WP's).

Each post has custom meta, which is stored in a separate table (postmeta table). In my case, I am storing city and state.

I've added some actions to WP's save_post/trash_post hooks so that the city and state are also stored in a separate table (cities) like so:

```
 ID    postID    city      state
auto    int     varchar   varchar
```

I did this because I assumed that this table would be faster than querying the rather large postmeta table for a list of available cities and states.

My logic also forced me to add/update cities and states for every post, even though this will cause duplicates (in the city/state fields). This must be so because I must keep track of which states/cities exist (actually have a post associated with them). When a post is added or deleted, it takes its record to or from the cities table with it.

This brings me to my question(s).

1. Does this logic make sense or do I suck at DB design?
2. If it does make sense, my real question is this: **would it be faster to use MySQL's "SELECT DISTINCT" or just "SELECT *" and then use PHP's array_unique on the results?**

**Edits for comments/answers thus far:**
The structure of the table is exactly how I typed it out above. There is an index on ID, but the point of this table isn't to retrieve an indexed list, but to retrieve ALL results (that are unique) for a list of ALL available city/state combos.

**I think I may go with (I don't know why I didn't think of this before) just adding a serialized list of city/state combos in ONE record in the wp_options table. Then I can just get that record, and filter out the unique records I need. 
Can I get some feedback on this?** I would imagine that retrieving and filtering a serialized array would be faster than storing the data in a separate table for retrieval.

Comment: I can't speak to 1, but the answer to 2 is almost certainly that MySQL will be faster.  That said, it's impossible to say without knowing more about your data - number of records, how indexed, etc.  But for most applications handling with MySQL will typically be faster than with PHP.

Comment: I'll leave question 1 to the others because I'm borderline incompetent with WP, but as for question 2 I'd recommend `SELECT DISTINCT` on the server. MySQL will probably process it just as quickly, and it's less traffic between the web and the database when the results are sent back.

Comment: consider the difference between the db pulling out and returning (say) 1000 distinct records from a billion record DB, v.s. the db sending those billion records over the wire and letting PHP do the filtering.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about using SELECT distinct vs. array_unique, I would say that I would almost always prefer to limit the result set in the database assuming of course that you have an appropriate index on the field for which you are trying to get distinct values.  This saves you time in transmitting extra data from DB to application and for the application reading that data into memory where you can work with it.

As far as your separate table design, it is hard to speculate whether this is a good approach or not, this would largely depend on how you are actually preforming your query (i.e. are you doing two separate queries - one for post info and one for city/state info or querying across a join?).

The is really only one definitive way to determine what is fastest approach. That is to test both ways in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

1) Fully normalized table(when it have only integer values and other tables have only one int+varchar) have advantage when you not dooing full table joins often and dooing alot of search on normalized fields. As downside it require large join/sort buffers and result more complex queries=much less chance query will be auto-optimized by mysql. So you have optimize your queries yourself.

2)Select distinct will be faster in almost any cases. Only case when it will be slower - you have low size sort buffer in /etc/my.conf and much more size memory buffer for php.

Distinct select can use indexes, while your code can't.
Also sending large amount of data to your app require alot of mysql cpu time and real time.